# Prevent Background Scrolling When Displaying Popup

Tags: jquery, html, popup

I have a form that is displayed in a popup. After loading, the background is grayed out, but the user can still scroll the background content up and down.

How do I prevent the background from scrolling?

[Example here](http://www.justsell.com/proverb-on-deeper-listening/)

the 'email this quote' link to the right of the pdf screenshot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One option is to temporarily set the `overflow` property to `hidden` on `body`, that will get rid of the scroll bars but causes a small flicker when the page is adjusted.

The other choice is to tap onto the `$(window).scroll()` event and return false from there. That will also cause a bit of flicker as the browser doesn't react that fast to the return false statement.

Your best bet is to move your click event handlers to a separate file and do the binding there:

```
$(function() {
    $('.emailPost').click(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() { return false; });
        pageTracker._trackPageview('/onclick/emailquote');            
    });
});
```

That should prevent a page from scrolling. Remember to remove the bind after the dialog closes, otherwise the page won't be scrollable anymore! You can remove binds using:

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

Comment: Thank you. But would this solution cause screen flickering? 
Also, the pageTracker is passed through a custom field set up in Wordpress, and would not be easy to interface with jQuery.

Comment: I have the same situation.  This is a nice solution, as it does lock the scroll in FF24.0, but it still allows the page to move using end/home/pageup/pagedown; also, it does not appear to work in IE8.  I haven't tested it further than those two browsers, but the above comment seems to show that this question needs some work.

Answer (score 31):

To hide the scrollbar of the body when opening the popup

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

and to revert back when closing the popup

```
document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
```

Comment: Assigning overflow hidden will cause the scroll bar to disappear, thus changing the page width.  This does not disable the scroll bar, though it does prevent scrolling from occurring.

Comment: Your solution works but when you close the Pop-up and again enable It scroll it is also giving horizontal scroll. Which is not required.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78139779/52499) to find out how to avoid page flickering.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the # tag in your links!

It will try to to scroll to the anchor # but because it's empty it will scroll to the top of the page.

Edit your links to:

`<a href="" onclick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('/onclick/emailquote');" class="emailPost">Email this quote</a>`

(notice the href="")

Comment: Absolutely do use the hash tag and do not in any case use inline JavaScript. To prevent the browser from redirecting to #, you can use `return false;` at the end of the handler function. http://crisp.tweakblogs.net/blog/313/the-useless-javascript-pseudo-protocol.html

Comment: Sorry, Rogier, that did not solve the issue. It also makes it so the page reloads which closes the popup. Thanks though!

Comment: Yeah, you still will have to use return false ofcourse!

But that is really basic JS ;)

`<a href="" onclick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('/onclick/emailquote');return false;" class="emailPost">Email this quote</a>`

Will work fine.

Comment: What about "javascript:void(0);"?

Comment: Whatever is in the href is immaterial as the 'return false' prevents the browser from going to that address. Keep in mind that you are wasting bandwidth by putting in anything but the _bare minimum_ -- some low traffic sites don't care about such things, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

This code block works for IOS mobile devices where the scroll issue is very common.

```
$('body').on('touchmove', function(e) {
    if ($('.scroll-disable').has($(e.target)).length) e.preventDefault();
});
$('body').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).addClass('scroll-disable');
});
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('scroll-disable');
});
```

Comment: Just ran into this iOS problem but sadly this solution doesn't seem to work on iOS 11.x/JQuery Mobile 1.45

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `overflow: hidden` solution is that it causes the page to flicker, because the page width changes when the scrollbar disappears. A solution? Fix the document width while displaying the popup:

```
document.body.style.width = document.body.clientWidth + 'px';
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyuri/179h6do5/) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/99bdbe2f4013a8f124bc1f2058734fcd).

<sub>Also I'm including my [deleted Code Review question](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/ddd5e9bd017c7d4b78af078da6e19ed4). It might be unnecessarily complex, especially these days (I wrote the code somewhere in 2010s). But it might contain solutions for further problems you might encounter. Although at the moment I see none.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

If you are using it like this

```
<a href="#targetid">Open Model</a>
```

(#tragetid) is the div popup id.

You can use and replace `href=""` with `data-mfp-src=""`. It's working perfectly.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Is this supposed to be a comment to another answer?