# Prevent page scrolling to top upon adding fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm facing a problem where the page is scrolling to the top whenever I add my `.noscroll` class to the body. This way the scrollbar is still visible but greyed out whenever the overlay appears.

I know that it's the addClass() function that is the cause of this because when I comment out that line, it doesn't scroll to the top when my overlay appears.

**jQuery**

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    //reset default anchor behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    //add noscroll class to body
    $("body").addClass("noscroll"); 

    //open overlay box
    openOverlayBox(); 
});
```

The `openOverlayBox()` function is simply a full browser screen overlay with a black tint.

**CSS**

```
body.noscroll{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**Body HTML**

```
<a href="#">Test</a>
```

How can I make the scroll position stay the same after the `.noscroll` class has been added to the body?

**EDIT 1:** I'm trying to achieve the same as on Facebook. If you view a picture or video, the overlay appears, the scrollbar is greyed out but the scrolled position is maintained.

**EDIT 2:** I found a very close [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16134959/1115367) to my issue, but the only thing is that this does not grey the scrollbar out, but just removes it. Also when the content is centered in the middle, it still makes the content jump a little to the right because the scrollbar from the body is hidden.

**EDIT 3:** After Cuberto's answer and some research of myself I found out what needs to be done to get it working I want. However I don't have a clue how I would start doing it. But this is what should solve it. I when opening the overlay I need to set my main div on `position: fixed` and a negative top value of the scroll position. When exiting the overlay, the `position: fixed;` and `top` attribute should be removed and the same scroll position set as when the overlay was opened.

Comment: Position fixed will do that !

Comment: Is there a way to not make it do that? Because when I check how it is on Facebook, the scrolled position is maintained.

Comment: negative on that Edit #3.  View my answer and you'll have the fix.  I'm confident you'll be satisfied.

Comment: I've found this gist to be helpful:  [jquery.scrollLock.js](https://gist.github.com/barneycarroll/6550066) - "Lock and unlock a page's scroll position".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Taking a quick look at how facebook does it, it's something like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="main" style="position: fixed; top: -400px"></div>
  <div class="overlay" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
</body>
```

Sorry for the inline styles. You need to programmatically set the main `div`'s `top` style to your scroll position.

Comment: This is the only answer that has worked for me in handling scroll prevention for iOS in a reliable way, without having to resort to preventing touchmove events from firing, and I find this perferable!

Answer (score 23):

***I believe this is what you are looking for.***

Hope you enjoy [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQHhg/6/).  I took the one you referenced at the end of your question and re-worked it the way you wanted.

I happened to have done something similar to this on my site but I never restricted the scrolling underneath until now.

---

### Javascript + jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var offsetY = window.pageYOffset,
        $body = $('body'),
        $win = $(window),
        $close = $('.close'),
        $open = $('.open'),
        $holder = $('#popupholder'),
        $stuff = $('#stuff');
    // Close with 'esc' key
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) $close.trigger('click');
    });
    $open.click(function () {
        offsetY = window.pageYOffset;
        // Block scrolling
        $body.css({
            'position': 'fixed',
                'color': '#FFFF00',
                'backgroundColor': '#00D',
                'top': -offsetY + 'px'
        });
        // Show popup
        $holder.css('display', 'block');
    });

    $close.click(function () {
        // Allow scrolling again
        $body.css({
            'position': 'static',
                'color': '',
                'backgroundColor': ''
        });
        /**
         * Remove the following scrollTop()'s if you want.
         * just a UI tweak that the user would expect.
         **/
        // Make the page stay at the position it was at before the overlay
        $win.scrollTop(offsetY);
        // Reset the overlay scroll position to the top
        $stuff.scrollTop(0);
        // Hide popup
        $holder.css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

### CSS:

```
#popupholder {
    max-height: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrap {
    max-height: none;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 60px;
    right: 60px;
    left: 60px;
    bottom: 60px;
    background-color: rgba(155, 155, 134, 0.5);
    display: block;
}
#stuff {
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    top: 0;
    /* If you want the scrollbar inside the overlay to show up, set right: 0; */
    right: -20px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

### HTML:

*(abridged version)*

```
<div id="popupholder">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="stuff">
            <button class="close">Close me</button>
            <p> Inside information </p>
            <button class="close">Close me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<button class="open">Popup</button>
```

Original code credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253802/js-css-disable-scrollbar-but-keep-scroll-position/16134959#16134959).  Code was highly altered but credit given where credit is due.

Comment: Why theres downvotes for this answer? Seems like working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts with when you open the modal or any overlay the background scroll is still enabled, to prevent this we add overflow: hidden; CSS which works efficiently on almost all browsers and OS. But we have a problem with IOS and some Linux browsers. So to fix this we added another CSS position: fixed; Which fixed the problem but it gave birth to a new problem.

After adding the CSS position: fixed; the body scrolls automatically at the top and loses the actual position which creates a wrong impression of the website.

I have fixed this problem by defining one variable outside the main container and updating its value only when the modal is closed. Then scroll the body again to the same position when the modal is closed.

```js
let scrollY = 0;
//defining outside because when when modal is open that body scrolls to top and make it 0 again and lost scroll position

const Component = () => {
  modalVisibleHandler = (value) => {
    if (value) {
        scrollY = window.scrollY;
        
        //add all added css when modal is open to prevent scrolling background
        
        document.body.style.position = 'fixed';
        document.body.style.top = `-${scrollY}px`;
        document.body.style.width = '100%';
    } else {
        //remove all added css when modal is close
        
        document.body.style.position = '';
        document.body.style.top = '';
        document.body.style.width = '';
        window.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
    }
  }
}
```