# Disabling scrollbars on a popup window

Tags: html, css

Im trying to open a pop-up window using the button below.

```
<form>
<button onClick="OpenPopupCenter('test.php','Name',700,500)">Test Button</button>
</form>
```

The function "OpenPopupCenter" is a script created to center the popup window.. See below.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function OpenPopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
            var left = (screen.width - w) / 2;
            var top = (screen.height - h) / 4;  // for 25% - devide by 4  |  for 33% - devide by 3
            var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
        } 
    </script>
```

When the popup window opens I would like to disable the ability to scroll?

Comment: Can we assume you have control over the `test.php` file?

Comment: @Roberrrt honest question, no snark: why do you think that's relevant?

Comment: You could simply set it to `overflow: hidden` ?

Comment: ^ Exactly Jake's comment @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: @Roberrrt oh, wait, `window.open`. I was thinking of fake pop-overs, for some reason

Comment: @Jake where would I add ```overflow: hidden``` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable scrolling while popup active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701289/disable-scrolling-while-popup-active)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to `test.php` file.

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This can only be done when we have control over the opened file, and will not work if there's a full screen div inside the test.php file with scrolling enabled through overflow.

Comment: Do i insert that code into the css file of test.php or the actual file?

Comment: @HTML-Help If you have control over test.php file you can solve the problem by adding this css code into the test.php file.