# How to disable the scrollbar on the background of the page when my pop-up is active

Tags: html, css

I am displaying some content via a pop-up and I want to disable the background scroll. What is a good way to do this via CSS?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. Please provide some code and rephrase your question. Also, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Go and have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701289/disable-scrolling-while-popup-active

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS property overflow to show or hide scroll bars.

overflow-x -> Horizontal scroll bar
overflow-y -> vertical scroll bar

```
overflow-y: hidden; // hides vertical scroll bar
```

Please refer the documentation in w3School https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

Comment: Generally, scroll bar will appear, if his content is longer than the fixed modal box it's wrapped in. overflow: hidden; will remove some of that content. So it really depends on the use case.